# this is undefined when calling variable set to static method

Tags: javascript, this

```
var Test = (function() {
    return {
        someValue: 69,
        staticMethod: function(){
          return this.someValue;
        }
    }
}());

console.log(Test.staticMethod());

var doIt = Test.staticMethod
console.log(doIt())
```

Output:

```
69
undefined
```

Expected:

```
69
69
```

---

Why does the `this` not exist in the context of the second call?

Demo: http://jsbin.com/kidefoniko/edit?js,console

Comment: Because the function is called without the object as context. The this-value of any function depends on execution context.

Comment: so the correct way is `doIt.call(Test)` ? What if I don't know that it was Test? Is there anyway to find out its context

Comment: Not really, the context is whatever you set, it's not predefined. When you do `Test.staticMethod()` you set the context to `Test`, in the second example you create a reference to the function, and then call it without context, so you have to use `call`, `apply` or `bind` to set the context instead.

Comment: In JS the `this` in the `staticMethod` function represents the object from where the `staticMethod` is invoked. In your first call you invoke it from Test object and it has `someValue` property but in your second invocation you invoke it from the `doIt` object which has no property named `someValue` hence you get "undefined". `this` has only 4 use cases in JS. For a better understanding of the `this` in JS i would recommend you to read this answer. http://qr.ae/RO44Vn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doIt` references to the same function `staticMethod` does:

```
function(){
   return this.someValue;
}
```

`this` is basically the object before the `.`
In case of this call: `Test.staticMethod()` it is `Test`

but here: `doIt()` there is no `.`, so no object before the dot.
In such cases `this` is assigned to the global object (if not in a strict mode). Global object (`window` in a browser) has no property called `someValue` therefore `undefined` is logged out.